# Typewritter Effect with CSS issue adding third line of text

Tags: html, css

I have been developing a website for my new company and want to include a typewriter effect on the main page, I have found a tutorial by [Medium.com](https://medium.com/@valentyn.vasylenko/typewriter-effect-with-alternating-text-in-pure-css3-72cf0c7e6c5) and I am running into an issue with adding another span to the code provided, look at the link above to see how it was setup Currently, I have as follows.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text_1 {
  animation: text1;
}

.text_2 {
  animation: text2;
}

.text_1,
.text_2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(25, end);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.text_1::after,
.text_2::after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  animation: caret infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
}

@keyframes text2 {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  60%,
  90% {
    width: 6em;
  }
}

@keyframes text1 {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  10%,
  40% {
    width: 10em;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h2><span class="text_1">Coastal Media Provides</span><span class="text_2">Photography</span></h2>
</div>
```

How would I go about adding a text_3 to the span, if I do so how they added span2 it does not work? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can see one difference between the snippet provided here and the code written in the blog.
The provided snippet is wrapper inside h2 like this

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h2><span class="text_1">Coastal Media Provides</span><span class="text_2">Photography</span></h2>
</div>
```

but the css has styling related to h1 and not h2.

> ```
> h1 {
>   font-size: 30px;
> }
> ```

```
.text_1 {
  animation: text1;
}

.text_2 {
  animation: text2;
}
```